# Save my Emacs registry entries without having to use desktop-save

Tags: desktop, registers

I frequently create registry entries which I wish to keep across Sessions. Emacs does not save registry entries across sessions. This can be done by using desktop-save, but the downside is that desktop-save also saves buffers across sessions and in my experience is generally temperamental. (I have frequently lost information saved this way.) I have also tried saving them by adding the register-alist to savehist-additional-variables but this did not work for me. In short, I would like to save my registry entries without having to use desktop-save, i.e. in the simplest way possible.

Comment: How about using desktop.el but with `desktop-files-not-to-save` set to `".*"` ?